# EF issues with 2 foreign keys going to same table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using the new ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 7.0 RC1 Final. I have two fields with a one-to-many relationship between Standards and Students. If I just have the one FK and Navigation Key the code works just fine, but when I add in the second FK (Standard2) and Nav field (Students2) I get the following error message:
**InvalidOperationException: The navigation 'Students' on entity type 'TestProject.Models.Standard' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType ignored.**

```
    public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {

    }

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public IList<Student> Students2 { get; set; }

}

    public Student()
    {

    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Standard
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public int StandardId2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardId")]
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardId2")]
    public Standard Standard2 { get; set; }
}
```

How do I have two FK's to the same table in EF 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to specify the other end of your relationships by using `InverseProperty` attribute, something that EF cannot infer on its own and hence throws an exception:

```
public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Standard")]
    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Standard2")]
    public IList<Student> Students2 { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can achieve the same results by using fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Students)
    .WithOne(s => s.Standard)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.StandardId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Students2)
    .WithOne(s => s.Standard2)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.StandardId2);
```